# JavaScript Hide/Show

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a project, and the actions (CRUD) are split into forms and divs. The divs have a function (hide/show), but I want to know **how can I show just 1 div at a time**, because the current function allows to show more than 1 div at a time and I don't want that to happen. The code is just a test.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
 if (x.style.display === 'none') {
  x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
  x.style.display = 'none';
 }
}
function myFunction2() {
 var x = document.getElementById('myDIV2');
 if (x.style.display === 'none') {
  x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
  x.style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Teste</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td>Teste 1</td>
    <td>Teste 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a onclick="myFunction()">Show/Hide</button></td>
    <td><button onclick="myFunction2()">Show/Hide</button></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="myDIV">
   <h1>Teste 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="myDIV2">
   <h1>Teste 2</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should hide other DIV, when open another.

Like:

when show DIV = hide DIV2

when show DIV2 = hide DIV

Answer (score 0):

This common example can be treated with `jQuery` [`accordion`](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
hideAllDivs();

function myFunc(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    hideAllDivs();
        x.style.display = 'block';

        } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function hideAllDivs() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  if (divs.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something like that, thanks for clearing my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

As you have included jQuery in your code, I will give you a jQuery based answer.

You have two buttons:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show/Hide</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Show/Hide</button>
```

You can remove the `onclick` and give them classes instead:

```
<button class="showhide-1">Show/Hide</button>
<button class="showhide-2">Show/Hide</button>
```

And you can give the `<div>`'s you want to Hide/Show a class (which will be `myDIVS` for the example) and optionally you can use `style="display: none;"` to hide them both when the page loads.

```
<div id="myDIV" class="myDIVS" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Test 1</h1>
</div>
<div id="myDIV2" class="myDIVS" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Test 2</h1>
</div>
```

Now you just need the jQuery code:

First we need to select the first button using its class, and capture all click events on it, like this:

```
$('.showhide-1').click(function() {
});
```

Inside that, you need to 1. Hide `#myDIV2` and 2. Show `#myDIV`.

```
  $('#myDIV2').hide();
  $('#myDIV').toggle();
```

Now just do the same again for the other button:

```
$('.showhide-2').click(function() {
  $('#myDIV').hide();
  $('#myDIV2').toggle();
});
```

```js
$('.showhide-1').click(function() {
  $('#myDIV2').hide();
  $('#myDIV').toggle();
});
$('.showhide-2').click(function() {
  $('#myDIV').hide();
  $('#myDIV2').toggle();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="showhide-1">Show/Hide</button>
      </td>
    <td>
        <button class="showhide-2">Show/Hide</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <div id="myDIV" class="myDIVS" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Test 1</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="myDIV2" class="myDIVS" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Test 2</h1>
 </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RafaelBreno How's my answer?